# SQL Server 2005 : str(4.65,5,1) = 4.7, str(3.65,5,1) = 3.6?

Tags: sql, sql-server, sql-server-2005

In SQL Server 2005 `str()` behaves strange on some float values while rounding. While searching in net, I found the below code and explanations there.

```
select STR(4.65,5,1) -- it will give 4.7
select STR(3.65,5,1) -- it will give 3.6
```

I got some explanations [here](http://www.sqlservercentral.com/questions/T-SQL/94788/) and [here](http://www.sqlservercentral.com/Forums/Topic1386032-3270-1.aspx), but didn't get anything from there *(that above T-SQL taken from one of the explanations link)*

Could anyone please explain why it behaves like this?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Syntax of [STR()](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms189527.aspx); `STR ( float_expression [ , length [ , decimal ] ] )` clearly says that the number is a `float_expression`. Therefore whatever the number you give it will be first converted to a `FLOAT(n)` where default value of **n = 53**.

So

```
SELECT STR(4.65,5,1), SELECT STR(3.65,5,1)
```

Equal to:

```
SELECT STR(CAST(4.65 AS FLOAT(53)),5,1) , STR(CAST(3.65 AS FLOAT(53)),5,1)
```

If you specify n, say **n = 4** it will give the answer you are expecting (ie; 4.7 and 3.7)

```
SELECT STR(CAST(4.65 AS FLOAT(4)),5,1) , STR(CAST(3.65 AS FLOAT(4)),5,1)
              --4.7,                     3.7
```

Comment: from BOL: "SQL Server treats n as one of two possible values. If 1<=n<=24, n is treated as 24. If 25<=n<=53, n is treated as 53." There is no FLOAT(n) in MSSQL, it's an alias. Underneath everything is REAL (single-precision) or FLOAT (double-precision). Better cast TO DECIMAL(5, 1) instead of formatting in the DB. STR function returns VARCHAR.